# Overflow issue math expression Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to show math expression in flutter app using [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#mathml) package. But unable to fix overflow issue, I do not want to **trim/ellipsis or fade** the expression

I want to show the complete expression using horizontal scroll

[image]

and my code is

```
SingleChildScrollView(
 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
 child: HtmlContent(htmlData: formatedTitle),
)
```

**HtmlContent Widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

class HtmlContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? htmlData;
  final Map<String, Style>? htmlCustomStyle;

  const HtmlContent({Key? key, this.htmlData, this.htmlCustomStyle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: (() {
        if (htmlData!.contains("img") || htmlData!.contains("table"))
          return deviceSize.width < 800
              ? Container(child: InteractiveViewer(child: htmlWidget(context)))
              : htmlWidget(context);
        else
          return htmlWidget(context);
      })(),
    );
  }

  htmlWidget(context) {
    return Html(
      data: htmlData,
      style: htmlCustomStyle == null ? htmlStyle : htmlCustomStyle!,
      customImageRenders: {
        (attr, _) => attr["src"] != null && attr["src"]!.startsWith("/media"):
            networkImageRender(
          mapUrl: (url) => baseURL + url!,
          loadingWidget: () => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        )
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The overflow problem is only with math expression, except for math expression everything is perfect, I have tried using **Expanded/Flexible/SizedBox/FittedBox/Container with BoxConstraints**

**Complete Widget**

```
Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: HtmlContent(
                              htmlData: widget.formatedTitle,
                            ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Question Hint",
                        style: labelStyle,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Container(
                          child: (widget.questionHint.contains("math-tex"))
                              ? Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: TeXView(
                                    renderingEngine: widget.renderingEngine,
                                    loadingWidgetBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context) {
                                      return Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: TeXViewDocument(widget.questionHint),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : widget.questionHint.contains("</math>")
                                  ? SingleChildScrollView(
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      child: HtmlContent(
                                          htmlData: widget.questionHint))
                                  : HtmlContent(htmlData: widget.questionHint)
                          )
                    ],
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your `HtmlContent(htmlData: formatedTitle)`

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code in Post

Comment: @IndrajeetSingh can you share code so we can test it properly? eg add your html code and the code for the box where you show the question hint, because currently I can only test it with some simple html which just wraps at the end of the line ...

Comment: Hi @Wouter I have tried using Expanded/Flexible/SizedBox/FittedBox/Container with BoxConstraints but there is no luck, the overflow problem is only with math expression, except for math expression everything is perfect.. I have updated the code In the Post

Answer (score 0):

Please check **Expanded** widget in HtmlContent class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

class HtmlContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? htmlData;
  final Map<String, Style>? htmlCustomStyle;

  const HtmlContent({Key? key, this.htmlData, this.htmlCustomStyle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: (() {
        if (htmlData!.contains("img") || htmlData!.contains("table"))
          return deviceSize.width < 800
              ? Container(child: InteractiveViewer(child: htmlWidget(context)))
              : Expanded(child:htmlWidget(context));
        else
          return htmlWidget(context);
      })(),
    );
  }

  htmlWidget(context) {
    return Html(
      data: htmlData,
      style: htmlCustomStyle == null ? htmlStyle : htmlCustomStyle!,
      customImageRenders: {
        (attr, _) => attr["src"] != null && attr["src"]!.startsWith("/media"):
            networkImageRender(
          mapUrl: (url) => baseURL + url!,
          loadingWidget: () => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        )
      },
    );
  }
}
```